# solution1_s() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sol_s1'

Tags: python-3.x

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Instead of printing the solution, it produces this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "C:\Program Files\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1533,
>        in **call** return self.func(*args)
>       TypeError: solution1_s() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sol_s1'

```
solutions_s={
    "sol_s1":"if this is happeing to you, there is a bug in the software. call up your supplier and they will try and troubleshoot the phone. make sure you have all the latest updates installed",
    "sol_s2":"these are all signs of a virus. the deleting of applications is virus munching on your data, and pop ups on your scren is also a virus symptom. immiditely use your antivirus to look for the problem or take it to a repair shop where they can delete the virus",
    "sol_app":"check if you have enogh storage on your device, if you dont and that was the problem, then see if you can get a storage upgrade. However, if it isnt there is a good chance you have a virus on your phone. scan your phone with an antivirus, or let your local repair shop do it",
    "sol_pop":"if the pop ups are on a web browser, this is normal. try getting an ad blocker if it is bothering you, but do not click on them. however, if it is happening on the main screen, you have contracted a virus. use your antivirus orget it fixed at a repair shop",
    "sol_s3":"this is another sign of a software fault. the only one who can fix this is your supplier. contact them as soon as possible"}

def solution1_s(sol_s1):
    label20=Label(screen,text=solutions_s[sol_s1])
    label20.pack()
    sys.exit()
def solution2_s(sol_s2):
    label22=Label(screen,text=solutions_s[sol_s2])
    label22.pack()
    sys.exit()
def solution_app(sol_app):
    label23=Label(screen,text=solutions_s[sol_app])
    label23.pack()
    sys.exit()
def solution_pop(sol_pop):
    label24=Label(screen,text=solutions_s[sol_pop])
    label24.pack()
    sys.exit()
def solution3_s(sol_s3):
    label26=Label(screen,text=solutions_s[sol_s3])
    label26.pack()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Well, to state the obvious: You're calling the function in tkinter, without supplying an argument.

Answer (score 1):

When you put a variable in the function header like this:

```
def solution1_s(sol_s1):
```

Python expects that you pass it an argument, which can be anything, and names it `sol_s1` within the scope of that function.

However, you appear to want to look up the key `sol_s1` in the dictionary `solutions_s`, which you have declared in your script, instead.

Try this instead:

```
def solution1_s():
    label20=Label(screen,text=solutions_s['sol_s1'])
    label20.pack()
    sys.exit()
```

Here's some reading material with in-depth discussion on scopes and dicts:

[Scopes](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_scope_and_namespaces.html)

[Dictionaries](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm)

Comment: ach shucks, you need to put the key in quotes, of course.

Comment: sorry im new to python.. could you please explain @nlsdfnbch

Comment: See the answer - i've updated the code. I'll link some docs for you to read.